# I'm controlling a stepper motor with GPIO pins with a for loop in C++. If I add a sensor reading to the for loop the motor gets slow, loud, and jerky

Tags: stepper-motor, accelerometer, c++

I have a C++ script actuating a motor and getting an accelerometer sensor reading every 20th or so pulse to the stepper motor. My problem is that the sensor readings are interrupting the pulses. Without the sensor reading the motor runs quietly and smoothly. WITH the sensor readings the  NEMA 17 stepper motor sounds like it's straining. The motor gets jerky and slower.

The sensor reading lines of code and the motor actuating lines of code are in the same for loop.

It's written for an Nvidia Jetson AGX Xavier.
I know it's a lot of code, but the parts in question are just the parts near the middle with the motor and sensor lines in the for loop. They are the most indented lines if that helps you find them.

Before we get to the main code I want to share my attempt to solve this problem, which was to try running the motor code and the sensor code in parallel. I downloaded a few packages. None worked, but here is one attempt.
I was able to paste this attempt at parallelization into the long file below it. It was the jerkiest action from the motor yet and I got segmentation core dumped errors after three seconds when I ran it.

```
#include <omp.h>

#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++){
    int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
    if (tid%2==0) {
        accel_x = read_raw_data(file, accel_x_register_high);
        accel_y = read_raw_data(file, accel_y_register_high);
        accel_z = (read_raw_data(file, accel_z_register_high));
```

//          cout << accel_x << " " << i << endl;
} else {
std::cout << "This is line TWO" << "\n";

```
    // MOTOR
```

//          usleep(motor_speed);
GPIO::output(output_pin, curr_value);
usleep(motor_speed);
GPIO::output(direction_pin, the_clock);
curr_value ^= GPIO::HIGH;

```
    }
}
```

The entire file. My CMakeLists.txt is below this.

```
// MOTOR INCLUDES
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <iomanip>
#include <omp.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>

// for handling random array selection
#include <vector>
#include <signal.h>

#include <JetsonGPIO.h>


// GYRO INCLUDES
extern "C" {
    #include <linux/i2c-dev.h>
    #include <i2c/smbus.h>
}
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

// GRYO VARIABLES
int file;
int adapter_nr = 1;
const char* filename = "/dev/i2c-8";
int initialize_mpu(int file);
__s32 high;
__s32 low;
__s32 value;
int read_raw_data(int file, __u8 addr);

__u8 reg = 0x84;
__u8 res;

__s32 accel_x;
__s32 accel_y;
__s32 accel_z;

__s32 gyro_x;
__s32 gyro_y;
__s32 gyro_z;

__s32 gyro_x_register_high = 0x43;
__s32 gyro_y_register_high = 0x45;
__s32 gyro_z_register_high = 0x47;

__s32 accel_x_register_high = 0x3B;
__s32 accel_y_register_high = 0x3D;
__s32 accel_z_register_high = 0x3F;

char buf[10];


// MOTOR VARIABLES
int motor_speed = 700;
int output_pin = 7;
int direction_pin = 11;
float mini = 0;
float maxi = 800;
float spread = maxi - mini;
int current_position = (int) spread / 2;
int the_clock;
int go_here;
int spin;
constexpr int FLOAT_MIN = 0;
constexpr int FLOAT_MAX = 1;

// MOTOR FUNCTIONS
float rand_float() {
    random_device rd;
    default_random_engine eng(rd());
    uniform_real_distribution<float> distr(FLOAT_MIN, FLOAT_MAX);
    return distr(eng);
}
int new_pos(int current_position) {
    float r1 = (rand_float() * spread) + mini;

    return (int) r1;
};


int main() {
    
    // GYRO
    file = open(filename, O_RDWR);
    if (file < 0) {
        exit(1);
    }
    int addr = 0x68;

    if (ioctl(file, I2C_SLAVE, addr) < 0) {
         exit(1);
    }
    res = i2c_smbus_write_byte_data(file, addr, 0);
    if (res < 0) {
      /* ERROR HANDLING: i2c transaction failed */
    } else {
      /* res contains the read word */
    }
   
    if (write(file, buf, 3) != 3) {
      /* ERROR HANDLING: i2c transaction failed */
    }
    initialize_mpu(file);

    
    
    // MOTOR
    GPIO::setmode(GPIO::BOARD);
    // set pin as an output pin with optional initial state of LOW
    GPIO::setup(output_pin, GPIO::OUT, GPIO::HIGH);
    GPIO::setup(direction_pin, GPIO::OUT, GPIO::HIGH);
    int curr_value = GPIO::HIGH;
    
//     #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
    for (int x = 0; x < 200; x++){
        int tid = omp_get_thread_num();

        go_here = new_pos(current_position);
        int dir_to_pos = go_here - (int) current_position;

        if (dir_to_pos > 0) {
            the_clock = 1;
        } else {
            the_clock = 0;
        };

        current_position = go_here;

//         cout << dir_to_pos << " " << go_here << " " << the_clock << "\n";
        
        if (dir_to_pos < 0) {
            spin = dir_to_pos * -1;
        } else {
            spin = dir_to_pos;
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < spin; i++){

            if (i % 20==5) {
                accel_x = read_raw_data(file, accel_x_register_high);
                accel_y = read_raw_data(file, accel_y_register_high);
                accel_z = (read_raw_data(file, accel_z_register_high));

//                 gyro_x = read_raw_data(file, gyro_x_register_high) / 131.0;
//                 gyro_y = read_raw_data(file, gyro_y_register_high) / 131.0;
//                 gyro_z = read_raw_data(file, gyro_z_register_high) / 131.0;
//             cout << accel_x << " " << i << endl;

            } else {

            // MOTOR
//             usleep(motor_speed);
            GPIO::output(output_pin, curr_value);
            usleep(motor_speed);
            GPIO::output(direction_pin, the_clock);
            curr_value ^= GPIO::HIGH;


//             cout << gyro_x <<" " << gyro_y << " " << gyro_z << " " << endl;
            };
        };
    };
    
    
    GPIO::output(output_pin, 0);
    GPIO::cleanup();
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
};

// GYRO FUNCTIONS
// Send configurations to the MPU
int initialize_mpu(int file) {
    __u8 sample_rate_register = 0x19;
    __u8 power_mgt_register = 0x6B;
    __u8 config_register = 0x1A;
    __u8 gyro_config_register = 0x1B;
    __u8 interrupt_enable_register = 0x38;
 
    i2c_smbus_write_byte_data(file, sample_rate_register, 0x07);
    i2c_smbus_write_byte_data(file, power_mgt_register, 0x01);
    i2c_smbus_write_byte_data(file, config_register, 0x00);
    i2c_smbus_write_byte_data(file, gyro_config_register, 0x18);
    i2c_smbus_write_byte_data(file, interrupt_enable_register, 0x01);
}
// Read the data of two 8-bit registers and compile into one 16-bit value
// register_address is the first (high) register, register_address+1 is the low register
// E.g., if the two registers contain the 8-bit values 0x01 and 0x02, this
// function returns the value 0x0102
int read_raw_data(int file, __u8 register_address) {
    high = i2c_smbus_read_byte_data(file, register_address);
    low = i2c_smbus_read_byte_data(file, register_address+1);
 
    value = (high << 8 | low);
 
    // This converts it from an unsigned 0-63355 value
    // to a signed value between -32769 and 32768
    if (value > 32768)
        value = value - 65536;
}
```

The CMakeLists.txt file.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(MyProjecto)
find_package(JetsonGPIO)

add_executable(MyProject range_bound_motor_and_gyro.cpp)

target_link_libraries(MyProject JetsonGPIO::JetsonGPIO i2c)


find_package(OpenMP)
if (OPENMP_FOUND)
    set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_C_FLAGS}")
    set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
    set (CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}")
endif()
```

Comment: I'm not experienced in OMP, but you seem to try and distribute the loop into several threads, instead of parallelizing the sensor readout with the stepper control. Note that I2C reading may be time consuming.

Comment: I'm using an AGX Xavier and I think I'm going to send the instructions (over SSH?) to the motor to a Python program on a Raspberry Pi Zero W 2 as a string, and let it the pins on the RBPi get signals to the motor (and driver first). It's going to be awesome. The motor will just move its 700, or whatever pulses while the sensor taxes readings ever x steps.